# Undefined index: category_id in Magento 2 Import

Tags: magento2, import

I'm trying to import some data into magento for some custom atributes, it seems to get some far through the sheet and then errors with the following message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: category_id in /domains/http/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/Category/Plugin/Storage.php on line 52
```

Can anyone shed any light on this for me? Here is some example data for you:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code category_id is not in set condtion.

Please use **isset** function

like, if your code is like below

```
$data('category_id');
```

then use below conditon

```
if(isset($data('category_id')))
```

Check now.

Comment: But the file that's being mentioned above is a wordpress core file.